# What happens with the black hole's mass when a black hole disappears?

Tags: black-hole, stellar-evolution, singularity

If a black hole isn't "fed" by attracted matter, it disappears someday. But how is that even possible? What happens with the mass at its singularity? It can't just disappear or am I wrong with something? Where does the mass disappear to and how is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mass (equivalently energy) is radiated away as [Hawking radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawking_radiation).

Comment: But what happens with the matter from the singularity?

Comment: @user30007 Hypothetically, it's converted to energy and radiated away, as this answer says. I wrote "hypothetically" because Hawking radiation has never been observed.

Comment: @DavidHammen, shouldn't that be, "Theoretically,...?"

Comment: @user30007 The black hole singularity is also theoretical, and (hopefully) a quantum gravity theory will replace it. But in standard GR, a black hole singularity isn't like an object in space. Firstly, a singularity *never* exists in the past of any observer. And as described [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/144458/123208) "A singularity in GR is like a piece that has been cut out of the manifold. It's not a point or point-set at all".

Comment: @SolomonSlow - No, it should not. People abuse the word theory so much that it now has come to mean "a wild guess made after having chugged one too many margaritas." A scientific theory is the pinnacle of science. A hypothesis: Not so much, and least not yet. Hawking radiation is a scientific hypothesis rather than a scientific theory. This hypothesis that has a solid basis in both general relativity and quantum mechanics, but it remains hypothetical.

Comment: @DavidHammen, I'd have thought that in this forum at least, people would use "theory" in the sense that you mentioned; "pinnacle of science, etc." And, I'd have thought that "hypothesis" would be an idea, suggested by a theory, with consequences that either could be confirmed or invalidated by performing an experiment. I know language changes, and it's hard to fight that, but we _should_ fight it. It doesn't help science (or any other endeavor), when there's nobody left who understands the true meaning of things that were written a generation or more ago.